# Solr Beans (Invalid setter method. Must have one and only one parameter) without any reason?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, javabeans

Currently I am encountering the following problem with Solr 4.1 in combination with Lucene 4.1.

I have a Solr-Bean like this:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;

public final class Bean {

    @Field
    private int someInt;
    @Field
    private String someString;
    //Fields like this are just being updated for easier use of the bean
    private List<Integer> someStringSplitIntoIntegers

        //setters, rest is the same:
        public void setSomeInt(int someInt) {
            this.someInt = someInt;
        }

        //getters straightforward...

}
```

Now I want to add the bean to a Solr database via HttpSolrServer.addBean(bean) and I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Invalid setter method. Must have one and only one parameter
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder$DocField.storeType(DocumentObjectBinder.java:202)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder$DocField.<init>(DocumentObjectBinder.java:150)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.collectInfo(DocumentObjectBinder.java:119)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.getDocFields(DocumentObjectBinder.java:99)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder.toSolrInputDocument(DocumentObjectBinder.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.addBean(SolrServer.java:136)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.addBean(SolrServer.java:125)
    (...my call...)
```

But I don't get why. I have the class for more than one argument per setter several times but it is ok (it's even generated by Eclipse).

And now the question:

What am I missing? What could the reason for this be? Does a missing entry in the schema.xml cause these errors (what I doubt...)?

Thanks in advance.

Martin Braun

Comment: Can you actually post the whole bean?

Comment: I am afraid I can't do so. In the example I posted all of the special stuff.

Comment: Ok. Seems to be fixed. I used @Field on the getters as well which caused errors. I already tried removing it but then another error arised. So I changed it back. Furthermore, Solr Beans are not conform with boolean isBoolean() methods (which caused the new error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use a `Field` annotation directly on the setter method:

```
 @Field("cat")
   public void setCategory(String[] c){
       this.categories = c;
   }
```

make sure that you have an `int` field in the solr `schema.xml` called someInt

Cheers

Comment: accepted because it was the best answer (although it didn't solve my problem directly)

Comment: As per solr-5.4.1 schema.xml has changed to managed.schema file. Otherwise it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed on my own.

From the comments:

Ok. Seems to be fixed. I used @Field on the getters as well which caused errors. I already tried removing it but then another error arised. So I changed it back. Furthermore, Solr Beans are not conform with boolean isBoolean() methods (which caused the new error). – Martin Braun just now edit

Comment: what was error after removing @Field on getters? How you have handled it? Was the new error something like.. ` java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate object of class...`?

Comment: 1st question: sorry, can't remember it. but it could be related to solr not being conform with normal bean standards afaik (booleans have to be accessed via getBooleanValue() instead of isBooleanValue())