# how to convert facebook response to a string in json format?

Tags: java, json, facebook-graph-api, gson, restfb

I'm trying to get query response from Facebook and map it to user defined class:

I have following class:

```
class FBStory {
        @Field
        private String application_id;
        @Field
        private String application_name;
        @Field
        private String caption;
        @Field
        private String created_time;
        @Field
        private String description;
        @Field
        private String from;// user_Id
        @Field
        private String message;
        @Field
        private String name;
        @Field("objectId")
        private String object_id;
        @Field
        private String privacy;
        @Field("statusType")
        private String status_type;
        @Field
        private String story;
        @Field("storyId")
        private String id;
        @Field("storyUrl")
        private String link;
        @Field
        private String type;
        @Field
        private String updated_time;
        @Field
        private Set<CommentInfo> comments = new HashSet<CommentInfo>();//set of comment Id
        @Field
        private Set<String> likes = new HashSet<String>();
        @Field("storyTags")
        private Set<String> story_tags = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

And the facebook response for a query is:

```
Post[actions=[] application=null attribution=null caption=null comments=Comments[count=0 data=[]] createdTime=Mon Apr 01 08:16:28 IST 2013 description=null from=CategorizedFacebookType[category=null id=100000363414872 metadata=null name=Nitin Thokare type=null] icon=null id=100000363414872_555878751100900 likes=null likesCount=null link=null message=null messageTags={} metadata=null name=null objectId=null picture=null place=null privacy=Privacy[deny=null description=null friends=null networks=null value=] properties=[] source=null to=[] type=status updatedTime=Mon Apr 01 08:16:28 IST 2013 withTags=[]]
```

I was trying to convert above response to an object of above class using:

```
storyObj = gson.fromJson(restFBResponse.toString(), SolrFBStoryDoc.class);
```

But for `gson.fromJson()` the first parameter should be a String in `JSON` format. Hence I'm getting an error for above line of code:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 5
```

Is there any way by which I can convert `restFBResponse` to a proper `Json` string and then pass as first parameter to `gson.fromJson()`?

Answer (score 0):

I found it's possible using Solr Beans, but using Solr beans gave rise to it's own problems, one of them as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204380/solr-beans-invalid-setter-method-must-have-one-and-only-one-parameter-without/15204841?noredirect=1#comment22370385_15204841). So, to Overcome this I recieved response from Facebook in `JsonObject.class` format (i.e. connectionType) instead of `Post.class` as given below:

```
data = facebookClient.fetchConnection(connection, t, parameters)

where, 'fetchConnection' is defined as,

<T> Connection<T> fetchConnection(String connection, Class<T> connectionType, Parameter... parameters);
```